# CiviMail: Anonymous subscriptions are allowed to groups with visibility for users and administrators!

Tags: civimail

Today we realized that anonymous users may subscribe to internal mailinglist groups in following scenario:

1. We send a mass mailing to some internal groups which are not marked as public visible.
2. A user receiving this mailing uses his/her mailer's "List unsubscribe" feature which utilizes the mail header "List unsubscribe"
3. Civi sends a confirmation with an option to rollback the unsubscription for **all groups the mailing addresses** not only for those the user belongs to.
4. Use this rollback fetaure and the user besomes a member of all groups used in the mailing :(

If this is the expected behaviour,

- the help text for mailing groups visibility should be changed, I think. Atm it's stating something like "Choose »users and administrators« if only authed users may add members to this group." And
- the groups have to be filtered to include only those, the recipoient is member of.

CiviCRM version 5.25.0

Does anybody know how to block those unauthed subscriptions?

Comment: I just edited the automatic confrmation templates and removed the possibility to re-subscribe. Maybe this is enough. But is it secure?

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down. IMHO the rollback feature should only resusbcribe the user for the groups he/she was a member of in the first place. No idea though how this is implemented in CiviCRM's core code.